# How to know if SQL Server is in the cloud or on premises?

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql

I recently joined in new job, they are using Azure SQL Server. Initially I don't know that SQL Server is in Azure. I am wondering how can I know whether SQL Server is in Azure or on premises?

Comment: You could ask them. Be prepared to answer their follow up question: Why does it matter?

Comment: Azure has both a SQL Database service (nearly equivalent to SQL Server) and SQL Database Instances (native SQL Server, managed by Azure. And then there's always the option of you running SQL Server on your own, within a set of VMs or containers. Aside from asking your employer where the database is, you could look at the connection string, and see if it contains an Azure-based one (e.g. `....database.windows.net` for SQL DB Service)... In any case: This question is unfortunately off-topic here, as it's not a programming question, and is directly related to your company's app config.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute the query:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

The result will tell you if you are using Azure SQL Database or any other version/edition

** If you are talking about SQL Server on Virtual machine in the azure, then this is the same as local version/edition

Comment: Now I remember why I did not like this interface :-( . Well... back to MSDn to help people there